# WebRTC with livestream of videos

Tags: video, streaming, video-streaming, webrtc, live-streaming

I am doing one plataform that streams video, but I want that this plataform makes live streamings in real time.
How do I do **live-Streaming** of videos with webRTC? Do I have another
alternatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With WebRTC usually people build p2p streaming platforms:  from browser to browser.

But this may be a problem if you want to record this video, so you will need some server that can proxy video from WebRTC to WebRTC and record it.

For server you can use something like opensource Kurento (couldn't launch it), or commercial Flussonic (I'm working on it) or Wowza.

But you need to know that current WebRTC implementations are limited by supported codecs, so for example with H264 you will get only baseline.

Comment: Excellent factual answer.  Rare for WebRTC on Stack Overflow.  :-)

Comment: It is also important to mention that there are a lot of "webrtc servers" on github, but 99% of them are only "signaling" servers. It mean that they only can connect two browsers via websockets in some virtual room and help to exchange text SDP.